# Apt Terminal Progress Bar source code Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, launchpad

I have read an article in OMG Ubuntu[0] about enabling the progress bar in the terminal.
I'm browsing apt launchpad page [1] and browisng the code. Someone knows exactly where is the code for the progress bar? I'm browising the correct launchpad page code or is another?

Thanks in advance

[0]http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-enable-apt-terminal-progress-bar
[1]https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/apt/trusty

Comment: Neat effect: try typing and pressing Enter while apt works => the text above scrolls but the progress bar is left in place.  `SetupTerminalScrollArea()` contains the magic: it uses [VT100 escape sequence that limits scrolling region](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html#S5.5.2.4).  This is brilliant because the rest of apt/dpkg/install scripts can go on spilling to stdout without caring about the progress bar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the definition of PackageManagerFancy::PackageManagerFancy() in the debian git repo of the apt source package:

The file providing the Fancy progress bar is [apt-pkg/install-progress.cc](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=apt/apt.git;a=blob;f=apt-pkg/install-progress.cc;h=bfc00bd063bed5196a7c57ffa24c5945c6b6b04d;hb=5ed887855df9c39dcd22971073ed05b28a9ee95f#l226)

Comment: I thought this was on la Bazaar code in launchpad

Comment: The same [file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/apt/trusty/view/head:/apt-pkg/install-progress.cc#L233) in bzr